# Setting Range based on Selection

Tags: vba, hyperlink, outlook

I want to take a reference number in an email to highlight and replace with a direct link to web page.

The current code will place the new hyperlink at the start of the email instead of the selected areas (currently `wddoc.Range(0 , 0)`).

If I use `Selection` it says the variable is undefined by user.

```
Sub AddHyperlink()
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oLink As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim strLink As String
Dim strLinkText As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strText As String

On Error Resume Next
'Get Outlook if it's running
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

'Outlook wasn't running, so cancel
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Outlook is not running so nothing can be selected!"
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

With OutMail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    strText = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Text
End With

strLink = "http://website.com/#" & strText & "" ' the link address
strLinkText = "" & strText & "" ' the link display text

On Error Resume Next
Set olEmail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

With olEmail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range(0, 0) '!!!Cannot find something that replaces range with current selection!!!!
    oRng.Collapse 0
    Set oLink = wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=oRng, _
                         Address:=strLink, _
                         SubAddress:="", _
                         ScreenTip:="", _
                         TextToDisplay:=strLinkText)

    Set oRng = oLink.Range
    oRng.Collapse 0
    .Display
End With

lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

When I have a new email open in MS Outlook, I'll have a keyboard shortcut setup to run the code in VBA within Outlook.

Comment: Where are you running the code from?

Comment: When i have a new email open in ms outlook, I'll have a keyboard schortcut setup to run the code in VBA within outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook vba while working with [ActiveInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector), try the following.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rngSel As Word.selection

    If Application.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        Set wdDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor ' use WordEditor
        Set rngSel = wdDoc.Windows(1).selection ' Current selection

        wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, _
        Address:="U:\plot.log", TextToDisplay:="Here is the link"
    End If

    Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This would be to replace everything after the first 'end with'?

Comment: @dripdrop that is complete code, give it try- let me know

Comment: Changed word.document and word.selection because they were giving me errors to outlook.inspector and outlook.selection. Now i get a mismatch error on ' use WordEditor.